# Continuous positive Functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(x)=o(g(x))$ does not imply $F(x)=o(G(x))$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

I need to find continuous positive Functions $f$ and $g$ and we have $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$ and $G(x)=\int_0^x g(t)dt$ such that $f(x)=o(g(x))$ does not imply $F(x)=o(G(x))$.

Here  $f(x)=o(g(x))$ means $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)/g(x)=0$

I feel this would work with some logarithmic functions but I could not find out the exact functions to satisfy it.

Comment: What is o(g(x))?

Comment: I have edited with the definition

Comment: If $G(x)$ is unbounded for $x \to \infty$ then $f(x)=o(g(x))$ implies $F(x)=o(G(x))$ – think of L'Hospital's rule!

Comment: L'Hospital rule implies the other way around, it talks about derivatives of numerator and denominator.

Comment: L'Hospital says that  $\lim \frac{F(x)}{G(x)} = \lim \frac{F'(x)}{G'(x)} = \lim \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$ if the latter limit exists and if $G$ is unbounded.

Comment: Actually the reverse implication is false:  it may be that $f(x) \ll g(x)$ for most $x$, but occasionally $f(x)$ briefly overtakes $g(x)$ before decreasing again.  If the jumps are short and rare enough, they won't appreciably affect $F(x)$.  So we can arrange that $F(x) = o(G(x))$ even though $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)/g(x)$ doesn't exist (and so $f(x) \neq o(g(x))$).

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=e^{-2x}$ and $g(x)=e^{-x}$

So, $$\lim_{x\to∞}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$$

However, $$\lim_{x\to∞}\frac{F(x)}{G(x)}=\frac{\left(\frac12-\frac{e^{-2x}}{2}\right)}{1-e^{-x}}=\frac12$$

Answer (score 0):

Every pair of continuous functions $f,g:[0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$ such that $f(x) =o(g(x))$ and $\int_0^\infty g(x)\,dx<\infty$ gives a counterexample.